# Parabola GNU/Linux-libre installation: problem with key

Tags: package-management, gpg, pacman, signature, parabola

I'm trying to install Parabola GNU/Linux-libre (OpenRC) and I repeatedly get this error during `pacstrap /mnt base elogind udev-init-scripts`.

```
error: some-package: signature from "A Packager <a-packager@example.org>" is unknown trust
:: File some-package.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
```

*Note: I cannot copy and paste the actual error because I'm installing it on another machine, but the error is the one show above*.

I tried to fix it by trying to use the [commands listed on the parabola wiki](https://wiki.parabola.nu/Installation_Guide#Verification_of_package_signatures), but with no luck and then I realized something. I looked the key that repeatedly fails on keys.gnupg.net and I found out this line (I prefer to censor some part of the key to make it anonymous):

```
Type bits/keyID     cr. time   exp time   key expir
uid XXX YYY <XXX@email>
sig  sig3  ZZZ 2017-01-24 __________ 2018-01-24 [selfsig]
sig  sig3  ZZZ 2018-01-21 __________ 2018-07-20 [selfsig]
sig  sig3  ZZZ 2018-07-17 __________ 2019-07-17 [selfsig]
sig  sig3  ZZZ 2019-07-17 __________ 2020-01-13 [selfsig]
sig  sig3  ZZZ 2019-07-17 __________ 2020-01-13 [selfsig]
sig  sig3  ZZZ 2019-10-26 __________ 2020-01-13 [selfsig]
sig  sig3  ZZZ 2020-01-13 __________ 2020-07-11 [selfsig]
sig  sig3  ZZZ 2020-07-11 __________ 2021-01-07 [selfsig]
```

As far as I can tell, this key expires *today* and it has not been updated, hence the failure.

It's possible **and advisable** to bypass the problem by somehow (how?) tell parabola that the key is fine?

Thanks

Comment: If you have tried updating your 'keyring' packages and that hasn't worked, I would try asking on the Parabola [forums](https://labs.parabola.nu/projects/parabola-community-forum/boards).

Comment: I ended up bypassing the verification for that package by modifying `pacman` config. And then I reinstalled the next day (the author renewed their key)